# Regex expression to match anything between two strings that does not contain sequence

Tags: regex

I would like to create a regular expression that matches anything between two strings that does not contain a sequence in the middle.

Using this regular expression as an example: `front.*(?!exclude)\.back$`
I would like to match a string that is between front and back that does not contain exclude.

Test cases:

front_exclude.back - no match

front.back - match

front.helloworld.back - match

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
front(?:(?!exclude).)*\.back$
```

Comment: Also could you provide an explanation as to why your approach worked?

Comment: Sure! Based on your original question, I'm assuming you understand how a negative look-ahead assertion works. The `(?:(?!exclude).)*` matches a sequence of characters such that the negative look-ahead assertion `(?!exclude)` is included before each character in the sequence. This makes sure that the string "exclude" does not appear anywhere in the sequence of characters.

Answer (score 0):

```
import re

txt = "The <Org> rain <Ort> in <Org> Spain <Ort>"

tag_start = "<Org>"
tag_end = "<Org>"
tag_exclude = "<(.*?)>"

reg_pattern = "(" + tag_start + "(?:(?!" + tag_exclude + ").)*\ " + tag_end + ")"

x = re.findall(reg_pattern, txt)
```